# Is there a standard option workflow in F#?

Tags: f#, workflow, option-type, monads

Is there an option (maybe) wokflow (monad) in the standrd F# library?

I've found a dozen of hand-made implementations ([1](http://stevehorsfield.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/f-delayed-compositional-maybe-monad-workflow-full-source/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157154/implementing-the-haskell-maybemonad-in-f-how-can-we-get-this-lazy)) of this workflow, but I don't really want to introduce non-standard and not very trusted code into my project. And all imaginable queries to google and msdn gave me no clue where to find it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no Maybe monad in the standard F# library. You may want to look at [FSharpx](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/10/introducing-fsharpx.html),  a F# extension written by highly-qualified members of F# community, which has quite a number of useful monads.

Answer (score 26):

There's no standard computation builder for options, but if you don't need things like laziness (as added in the examples you linked) the code is straightforward enough that there's no reason not to trust it (particularly given the suggestively named `Option.bind` function from the standard library).  Here's a fairly minimal example:

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member x.Bind(v,f) = Option.bind f v
    member x.Return v = Some v
    member x.ReturnFrom o = o
    member x.Zero () = None

let opt = OptionBuilder()
```

Comment: I find it useful to add a `Zero` method to this: `member x.Zero () = None`.  This allows the following usage of the builder: `let thisIsNone = opt { if 2 + 2 = 5 then return "The impossible has happened" }`

Answer (score 2):

I've create an opensource library [FSharp.Interop.NullOptAble](https://ekonbenefits.github.io/FSharp.Interop.NullOptAble) available on nuget.

It not only works as an option workflow, but it works as a null or nullable workflow as well.

```
let x = Nullable(3)
let y = Nullable(3)
option {
    let! x' = x
    let! y' = y
    return (x' + y')
} (* |> should equal (Some 6) *)
```

Works just as well as

```
let x = Some(3)
let y = Some(3)
option {
    let! x' = x
    let! y' = y
    return (x' + y')
} (* |> should equal (Some 6) *)
```

Or even

```
let x = "Hello "
let y = "World"
option {
    let! x' = x
    let! y' = y
    return (x' + y')
} (* |> should equal (Some "Hello World") *)
```

And if something is `null` or `None`

```
let x = "Hello "
let y:string = null
option {
    let! x' = x
    let! y' = y
    return (x' + y')
} (* |> should equal None *)
```

Finally if you have a lot of nullable type things, I have a cexpr for `chooseSeq {}` and if you `yield!` something `null`/`None` it just doesn't get yielded.

See more examples [here](https://ekonbenefits.github.io/FSharp.Interop.NullOptAble/RealWorld.html).