# Constructing a record with a power of Applicative in F#

Tags: haskell, f#

Suppose there is a `type r = {A : int; B : string; C : int; D : string}` and a some values:

```ml
let aOptional : int option = ...
let bOptional : string option = ...
let cOptional : int option = ...
let dOptional : string option = ...
```

How can `r optional` could be constructed from them eleganlty (without nested case-stuff, etc.)?

---

Btw, here is how it could be done in haskell with [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html):

```hs
data R = R { a :: Integer, b :: String, c :: Integer, d :: String}

R <$> aOptional <*> bOptional <*> cOptional <*> dOptional :: Maybe R
```

Looking for something equivalent in fsharp.

Comment: So you want to create an instance of `r` but only if all four values are not `None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know (using applicatives) is by creating a function to construct the record:

```
let r a b c d = {A = a; B = b; C = c; D = d}
```

Then you can do:

```
> r </map/> aOptional <*> bOptional <*> cOptional <*> dOptional ;;

val it : R option
```

You can define `map` and `<*>` yourself, but if you want a generic implementation try that code with [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus) or if you want to use [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl) directly you can write the code this way:

```
#r "FsControl.Core.dll"

open FsControl.Operators

let (</) = (|>)
let (/>) f x y = f y x

// Sample code
type R = {A : int; B : string; C : int; D : string}
let r a b c d = {A = a; B = b; C = c; D = d}

let aOptional = Some 0
let bOptional = Some ""
let cOptional = Some 1
let dOptional = Some "some string"

r </map/> aOptional <*> bOptional <*> cOptional <*> dOptional
// val it : R option = Some {A = 0; B = ""; C = 1; D = "some string";}
```

**UPDATE**: [Nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsControl/) are available now.

Comment: Can't find it in the Nuget repository

Comment: Yes, there is no Nuget at the moment. You have to download the project and compile it. Someone has to create a Nuget for this project.

Comment: That's the idea, to share it and use it in most monad libraries.

Answer (score 5):

The straightforward way is:

```
match aOptional, bOptional, cOptional, dOptional with
| Some a, Some b, Some c, Some d -> Some {A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d}
| _ -> None
```

or, with a [maybe monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7823099/162396):

```
let rOptional = 
  maybe {
    let! a = aOptional
    let! b = bOptional
    let! c = cOptional
    let! d = dOptional
    return {A=a; B=b; C=c; D=d}
  }
```

Comment: +1 I was just going to write the same answer :-). There is no need for nested `match` because you can pattern match on all values at the same time - it may be a bit longer than Haskell, but it is clear and idiomatic F# solution.