# What is the typical definition/meaning of this F# operator <*>

Tags: f#, operators, functor, applicative

Being relatively new to functional programming, I am still unfamiliar with all the standard operators. The fact that their definition is allowed to be arbitrary in many languages and also that such definitions aren't available in nearby source code, if at all, makes reading functional code unnecessarily challenging.

Presently, I don't know what `<*>` as it occurs in [WebSharper.UI.Next](http://websharper.com/docs/ui.next) documentation.

It would be good if there was a place that listed all the conventional definition for the various operators of the various functional languages.

Comment: In VS 2015 with F# Power Tools, you can right-click an unfamiliar operator and "Go to Definition". This might not show you the source code, but it will show you to the type signature and any documentation comments. It wasn't always the case that you could do this with operators, but I'm not sure if  it was VS 2015 or the F# Power Tools that added this capability.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with you, it would be good to have a place where all implicit conventions for operators used in F# are listed.

The `<*>` operator comes from Haskell, it's an operator for [Applicative Functors](https://www.google.ch/#q=applicative+functors), its general signature is: `Applicative'<('A -> 'B)> -> Applicative'<'A> -> Applicative'<'B>` which is an illegal signature in .NET as [higher kinds](https://www.google.ch/#q=higher+kinds) are not supported.

Anyway nothing stops you from defining the operator for a specific Applicative Functor, here's the typical definition for option types:

```
let (<*>) f x =
    match (f, x) with 
    | Some f, Some x -> Some (f x) 
    | _              -> None
```

Here the type is inferred as:

```
val ( <*> ) : f:('a -> 'b) option -> x:'a option -> 'b option
```

which is equivalent to:

```
val ( <*> ) : f: option<('a -> 'b)> -> x: option<'a> -> option<'b>
```

The intuitive explanation is that it takes a function in a context and an argument for that function in the context, then it executes the function inside the context.

In our example for option types it can be used for applying a function to a result value of an operation which may return a `None` value:

```
let tryParse x = 
    match System.Int32.TryParse "100" with
    | (true, x) -> Some x
    | _ -> None

Some ((+) 10) <*> tryParse "100"
```

You can take advantage of currying and write:

```
Some (+) <*> tryParse "100" <*> Some 10
```

Which represents something like:

```
(+) (System.Int32.Parse "100") 10
```

but without throwing exceptions, that's why it is also said that Applicatives are used to model side-effects, specially in pure functional languages like Haskell. Here's [another sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104114/constructing-a-record-with-a-power-of-applicative-in-f) of option applicatives.

But for different types it has different uses, for lists it may be used to zip them as shown in this [post](http://bugsquash.blogspot.fr/2010/12/zipping-with-applicative-functors-in-f.html).

In F# it's not defined because .NET type system would not make it possible to define it in a generic way however it would be possible using overloads and static member constraints as in [FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl#how-can-i-make-my-classes-fscontrol-ready) otherwise you will have to select different instances by hand by opening specific modules, which is the approach used in [FSharpx](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/reference/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered elsewhere in the documentation on another subject...

```
    let ( <*> ) f x = View.Apply f x
```

where type of `View.Apply` and therefore `( <*> )` is:

```
    View<'A * 'B> -> View<'A> -> View<'B>
```