# Performing Calculations on F# option types

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write some function that handle errors by returning double options instead of doubles. Many of these functions call eachother, and so take double options as inputs to output other double options. The problem is, I can't do with double options what I can do with doubles--something simple like add them using '+'.

For example, a function that divides two doubles, and returns a double option with none for divide by zero error. Then another function calls the first function and adds another double option to it.

Please tell me if there is a way to do this, or if I have completely misunderstood the meaning of F# option types.

Comment: try to add some code samples illustrating what do you want to implement and what errors do you get

Comment: Something as innocent as Some(1.0) + Some(1.0) doesn't work. If it really doesn't work, then I can't really use it because I have a lot of functions that take double options and return double options, and they all depend on eachother to do some math.

Comment: What you are looking for is an option workflow. Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818277/is-there-a-standard-option-workflow-in-f).

Comment: ...or use just use `Option.bind`.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-bind/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called lifting - you can write function to lift another function over two options:

```
let liftOpt f o1 o2 = 
        match (o1, o2) with
        | (Some(v1), Some(v2)) -> Some(f v1 v2)
        | _ -> None
```

then you can supply the function to apply e.g.:

```
let inline addOpt o1 o2 = liftOpt (+) o1 o2
```

Comment: You can actually go even a step further to make the code more readable: Define liftOpt as done here, and then (do this *very, very locally*) shadow `+` with something like `let (+) o1 o2 = liftOpt(+) o1 o2`. And now you can write `let x, y = Some 3.0, Some 2.0` and then `x + y`.

Comment: @DanielFabian Good hint, the great place (IMO) to do that would be to put the lifted `(+)` in `module Option`, to extend the default `Option`. Then only after `open Option` you'd have the lifted `(+)` in scope :)

Answer (score 3):

`liftA2` as mentioned above will provide a general way to 'lift' any function that works on the `double` arguments to a function that can work on the `double option` arguments.

However, in your case, you may have to write special functions yourself to handle the edge cases you mention

```
let (<+>) a b =
    match (a, b) with
    | (Some x, Some y) -> Some (x + y)
    | (Some x, None)   -> Some (x)
    | (None, Some x)   -> Some (x)
    | (None, None)     -> None
```

Note that `liftA2` will not put the cases where you want to add `None` to `Some(x)` in automatically.

The `liftA2` method for divide also needs some special handling, but its structure is generally what we would write ourselves

```
let (</>) a b =
    match (a, b) with
    | (Some x, Some y) when y <> 0.0d -> Some (x/y)
    | _ -> None
```

You can use these functions like

```
Some(2.0) <+> Some(3.0) // will give Some(5.0)
Some(1.0) </> Some(0.0) // will give None
```

Also, strictly speaking, `lift` is defined as a "higher order function" - something that takes a function and returns another function.

So it would look something like this:

```
let liftOpt2 f =
    (function a b ->
        match (a, b) with
        | (Some (a), Some (b)) -> f a b |> Some
        | _ -> None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I realized what I was really looking for was the Option.get function, which simply takes a 'a option and returns an 'a. That way, I can pattern match, and return the values I want.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might want to consider Nullables over Options, for two reasons:

- Nullables are value types, while Options are reference types. If you have large collections of these doubles, using Nullables will keep the numbers on the stack instead of putting them on the heap, potentially improving your performance.
- Microsoft provides a bunch of built-in [Nullable Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370984.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that do let you directly perform math on nullables, exactly as you're trying to do with options.