# F# equivalent to Kotlin's ?. operator

Tags: kotlin, f#

I just started my first F# project and coming from the JVM world, I really like Kotlin's nullability syntax and was wondering how I could achieve similarily compact syntax in F#.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass {
    fun doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

// At some other place in the code:
val myNullableValue: MyClass? = null
myNullableVallue?.doSomething()
```

What this does:

1. If `myNullableValue` is *not* `null`, i.e. there is some data, `doSomething()` is called on that object.
2. If `myNullableValue` is `null` (like in the code above), nothing happens.

As far as I see, the F# equivalent would be:

```
type MyClass = 
    member this.doSomething() = ()

type CallingCode() = 
    let callingCode() = 
        let myOptionalValue: MyClass option = None
        match myOptionalValue with 
        |Some(x) -> x.doSomething()
        |None -> ()
```

A stamement that is 1 line long in Kotlin is 3 lines long in F#. My question is therefore whether there's a shorter syntax that acomplishes the same thing.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in operator for doing this in F# at the moment. I suspect that the reason is that working with undefined values is just less frequent in F#. For example, you would never define a variable, initialize it to `null` and then have some code that may or may not set it to a value in F#, so the usual way of writing F# eliminates many of the needs for such operator.

You still need to do this sometimes, for example when using `option` to represent something that can legitimately be missing, but I think this is less frequent than in other languages. You also may need something like this when interacting with .NET, but then it's probably good practice to handle `null`s first, before doing anything else.

Aside from pattern matching, you can use `Option.map` or an F# computation expression (there is no standard one, but it's easy to use a library or define one - see [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818277/is-there-a-standard-option-workflow-in-f)). Then you can write:

```
let myOptionalValue: MyClass option = None

// Option #1: Using the `opt` computation expression
opt { let! v = myOptionalValue 
      return v.doSomething() }

// Option #2: Using the `Option.map` function
myOptionalValue |> Option.map (fun v -> v.doSomething() )
```

For reference, my definition of `opt` is:

```
type OptionBuilder() =
  member x.Bind(v,f) = Option.bind f v
  member x.Return v = Some v
  member x.ReturnFrom o = o
  member x.Zero () = None

let opt = OptionBuilder()
```

Comment: I believe you would use `Option.iter` rather than `Option.map` for the function in the question, which returns `unit`. Alternatively use `|> ignore` for a more generic style.

Comment: @BentTranberg You're right - `iter` is the way to go for side-effecting computations! (And that is perhaps also yet another reason to write code in a way that does not require `nulls` and side effects!)

Comment: Of course, setting the value to `null` is something which is also disouraged in Kotlin, it was just for the sake of the example. My use case is one of those where there might legitimately be no data. One more question though: Why do I need the `opt` block? Can't I simply pipe `myOptionalVAlue` into `Option.map`?

Comment: @vatbub Sorry for the confusion, you do not need it. This was supposed to be two alternative options of doing the same thing. I clarified this in the answer.

Comment: Ah, in that case `Option.map` will probably be my way to go. I will mark your answer as the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The ?. operator has been suggested to be added to F#.

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/14

Some day it will be added, I hope soon.